# Fedora 33 as wireless router to the internet: stations are always isolated, cannot ping/connect between devices on the wireless lan

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, routing, hostapd, firewalld

Wifi adapter : Asus PCE-AC88

Running on the router : Fedora 33, firewalld, hostapd (built from master), dnsmasq

Routing to the internet works great, all stations are routed to the WAN provided by my isp (Xfinity) using a cable modem connected to the wired lan interface (enp4s0).

But the connected clients cannot communicate with each other, no ping, no arp discovery, totally isolated.

ifconfig output on the router:

```
enp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet <censored>  netmask 255.255.248.0  broadcast <censored>
        inet6 <censored>  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether <censored>  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4508572  bytes 5664501825 (5.2 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1793759  bytes 1160297835 (1.0 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 170  bytes 32986 (32.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 170  bytes 32986 (32.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::2efd:a1ff:fecf:2ee0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether <censored>  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1711022  bytes 1123229018 (1.0 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4455139  bytes 5651027770 (5.2 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Firewall is firewalld no iptables, two zones internal and external:

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --zone=external --list-all
external (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: enp4s0
  sources: 
  services: 
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 

$ sudo firewall-cmd --zone=internal --list-all
internal (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: wlp1s0
  sources: 
  services: dhcp dhcpv6-client dns mdns samba-client ssh
  ports: 5001/tcp
  protocols: icmp
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

Hostapd was built similarly to this page : https://gist.github.com/picchietti/337029cf1946ff9e43b0f57aa75f6556

Hostapd.conf (note that its not bridging) :

```
interface=wlp1s0
driver=nl80211
#I tried both settings of ap_isolate with the same results
ap_isolate=0
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd

logger_syslog=-1
logger_syslog_level=0

ssid=TestSSID
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
wpa_pairwise=CCMP
wpa_passphrase=<censored>
auth_algs=1

country_code=US
ieee80211d=1

hw_mode=a

ieee80211ac=1
vht_capab=[SHORT-GI-80][MU_BEAMFORMER]
vht_oper_chwidth=1
vht_oper_centr_freq_seg0_idx=42

ieee80211n=1
ht_capab=[VHT160][HT40+][SHORT-GI-40][SHORT-GI-160][DSSS_CCK-40]
wme_enabled=1
wmm_enabled=1
channel=36
```

dnsmasq.conf:

```
interface=wlp1s0
no-resolv
dhcp-range=192.168.1.10,192.168.1.250,255.255.255.0,12h
dhcp-option=3,192.168.1.1
dhcp-option=6,192.168.1.1
cache-size=1500
log-queries
log-dhcp
listen-address=192.168.1.1,127.0.0.1
server=75.75.75.75
server=75.75.76.76
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
```

Route tables on the router:

```
$ ip route
default via <isp gateway> dev enp4s0 proto dhcp metric 100 
<public net> dev enp4s0 proto kernel scope link src <public ip> metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp1s0 scope link metric 1004 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.1
```

The stations get assigned the default route but cannot ping each other:

```
$ ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wls7 proto static metric 600 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wls7 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.54 metric 600

$ ping 192.168.1.69
PING 192.168.1.69 (192.168.1.69) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.54 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.54 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.54 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

On the stations if I manually add a route back to the router:

```
$ sudo route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.1
```

Then they can communicate with each other (still no arp), but this should not be necessary, I tried this step just to make sure that the firewall was not getting in the way.

When I examine traffic using tcpdump:

```
$ sudo tcpdump ip proto \\icmp -i wlp1s0
```

I only see icmp traffic when the manual route on the station is added.

As an experiment I connected the same stations to my Galaxy Note 10 hotspot, which assigned similar routing tables as my router, and they can ping and connect with each other.

What is blocking traffic on the wireless network??

Thank you

Comment: did you figure this out?